# Get the actual node being used when connecting to a MongoDB replicaSet

Tags: php, mongodb, replicaset

I'm querying data from a `mongoDB` replica-set. The queries take quite a long time and I'd like to be sure that the data is not being read from the wrong node.

Is it possible to get the actual node being used for a given query?

I'm using the `PHP mongoDB` client.

Comment: Before you run a query on replicaset its difficult to know on which node the query will go. But once you have run the query and started iterating the cursor, it may be possible to get host information by runing info() method on cursor object. Check this - http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.info.php

Comment: With the default read preference, all queries go to the current primary. Always. Slow queries are usually a sign of bad indexing.

Comment: @AbhayPS thanks, post your comment as an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I've configured the readPreferences so preference is given to secondary nodes. Anyway I'd like to be sure that Mongo is choosing the closest host.

Comment: @gontrollez - glad that it solved the issue. I have posted the answer.

Comment: @gontrollez there is a "nearest" option for the read preference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have run the query and started iterating the cursor, it is possible to get information about the host where the query is run. You can get it by running `info()` method on `cursor` object. Check this - [php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.info.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.info.php)